# JavaScript error on eval statement

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying out this code in Firefox 47.0.1 using Firefox inspector from the console. I'm getting an error on the last eval statement:

```
eval( 'jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
```

I swear that the last eval was working around August 2016!  I'm getting this error

> SyntaxError: missing; before statement

Here is my code.  I found the first two eval statements work.

```
var debug  = 1;

newCode = `init: function(target, current){
        console.log ("   update:");
        this.data.pageIndex = current;
        this.pushState(target, current);
        this.getData(target);
    }`;
console.log ("newCode typeof is " + typeof newCode + " -->" + newCode+"<--");

var passString =  new String('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
console.log ("passString -->" + passString + "<--");
eval(passString);
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );

eval( new String('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode));
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );

console.log ("constant typeofis " + typeof ('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode) );

/* This eval gets an error */
eval( 'jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
console.log ("second eval completed." );
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );
```

Here is what I see in the console. I paste the code into the console then press enter.  I'm on this page 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7824331

```
var debug  = 1;

newCode = `init: function(target, current){
        console.log ("   update:");
        this.data.pageIndex = current;
        this.pushState(target, current);
        this.getData(target);
    }`;
console.log ("newCode typeof is " + typeof newCode + " -->" + newCode+"<--");

var passString =  new String('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
console.log ("passString -->" + passString + "<--");
eval(passString);
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );

eval( new String('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode));
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );

console.log ("constant typeofis " + typeof ('jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode) );

/* This eval gets an error */
eval( 'jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
console.log ("second eval completed." );
if ( debug ) console.log("--> update:\n"+window.jspaginate["init"].toString() );

newCode typeof is string -->init: function(target, current){
        console.log ("   update:");
        this.data.pageIndex = current;
        this.pushState(target, current);
        this.getData(target);
    }<--
passString -->jspaginate["init"] =init: function(target, current){
        console.log ("   update:");
        this.data.pageIndex = current;
        this.pushState(target, current);
        this.getData(target);
    }<--
--> update:
function (action, last){
        var view = this,
            target, current;
        if(this.loading !== true){
            view.loadingSequence();
            window.paginationActive = true;
            if(action === 'first'){
                target = 0;
                view.update(target, 0);
            }else if(action === 'prev'){
                current = parseInt(view.data.pageIndex)-1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }else if(action === 'next'){
                current = parseInt(view.data.pageIndex)+1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }else if(action === 'last'){
                current = parseInt(last)-1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }
        }
    }
--> update:
function (action, last){
        var view = this,
            target, current;
        if(this.loading !== true){
            view.loadingSequence();
            window.paginationActive = true;
            if(action === 'first'){
                target = 0;
                view.update(target, 0);
            }else if(action === 'prev'){
                current = parseInt(view.data.pageIndex)-1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }else if(action === 'next'){
                current = parseInt(view.data.pageIndex)+1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }else if(action === 'last'){
                current = parseInt(last)-1;
                target = (current)*view.data.range;
                view.update(target, current);
            }
        }
    }
constant typeofis string
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Comment: `'jspaginate["init"] =' + 'init: ...'`?

Comment: Also if you already have entire function hardcoded as string, why not do `jspaginate.init = function(){...}` Why do you even need `eval`?

Comment: there is absolutely no need to use `eval` for this - in fact, `eval` is *(almost)* never justified

Comment: I had problems before without the eval.  I'll try again.

Comment: Without the eval, the assignment statement appears to give the same output, I get a run time error.  TypeError: view.updateUI is not a function[Learn More]  0e4147337c7f4d0d5ab0f051fec58978.js:1057:13
 jspaginate.getData/<